# Python only recognizes first line among multilines

Tags: python

if I paste multi-lines input at once,
my program recognizes the first line only .

bible = input()
and if I paste

Do not be anxious about anything, but in everything,
by prayer and petition, with thanksgiving,
present your requests to God.

and after removing a blank, like, bible = bible.replace(' ',''),
when finally print(bible), it just prints out

Donotbeanxiousaboutanything,butineverything, (just first line of them).
2nd, 3rd lines are gone.

```
bible = ()
bible = bible.replace(' ','')
print(bible)
```

and my input is

```
Do not be anxious about anything, but in everything,  
by prayer and petition, with thanksgiving,  
present your requests to God.
```

expected output is

```
Donotbeanxiousaboutanything,butineverything,byprayerandpetition,withthanksgiving,presentyourrequeststoGod.
```

I want to include not only first line of input, but also rest of them and also in one string.

Comment: Can you put code blocks around the actual code in question or mark where your /n or /r/n is? Not sure where your input splits into a new line in your example there.

Comment: `input` returns as soon as it get a end-of-line.

Answer (score 1):

It can work for me with python 3

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
bible = ''.join(iter(input, ''))
bible = bible.replace(' ','')
print(bible)
```

Result : 
Donotbeanxiousaboutanything,butineverything,byprayerandpetition,withthanksgiving,presentyourrequeststoGod.

Comment: In effect you call `input` once for each line.